How can I make an anchor tag open link in new tab, in my Github repo's readme.md file
I tried using target attribute to open the anchor tag's link in new tab, but it doesn't work. How can I make the readme file open links in new tab?
<a href = "<link>" target="_blank"> click me </a>

I tried adding the target attribute to the anchor tag and I was expecting it to open the link in new tab.

Does this answer your question? open link in new tab with github markdown using target="_blank"

Unfortunately, this isn't possible on GitHub. They don't include the target attribute at all.

But I've seen repos with readme files which open an anchor tag in new tab? Is there any possible way I can do it?

I mean if you can find a repo that does that, you can just check their code. You can do testing yourself though, GitHub doesn’t enable target attributes.

I did checked that repo, They had their readme file coded in an entire diffrent language. By language I don't mean any programming language, but a diffrent language we speak, like some chinese or korean language it was.

This sounds very cryptic. Can you provide a link or it's an NSA-run repo with README.md in top-secret CIA language?
